# Generic fill shapes using Python & OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, fill

I want to know the area (number of 'white' pixels) of some shapes in a image.

After some image processing I'm getting a binary images like that:
[image]

And want to 'fill' the empty shapes in white and than count the white pixels to know the area of the shapes.

To do so I'm using this code:

```
# Filling shapes
kernel = np.ones((1000, 500), np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
```

And this gives me the expected image:
[image]

Than I'm counting the white pixels and gets the area (in pixels) of the shapes.

My issue is that the shapes is always different and I don't know how to make my code more generic to fill any other shapes -
For example this shapes image:
[image]

Gives me this unwanted result (in the left side in this case) with the same filling shapes code:
[image]

Any ideas what can I do for more generic fill kernel (or something else..)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your filling kernel extends from the figure to the edge of the image. That is why you get the white to the edge. One way is to pad your background image with black at least as much as your kernel size. Then do your processing and then crop the excess off afterwards.

Comment: But even in the first picture the kernel of the filling so-called goes beyond the edges and it does not extend outward from the shape. And what does it mean to pad in black? The entire image is black except for the shape itself

Comment: you need to besure it is a closed contour, maybe contour is not closed

Comment: Flood-fill at some corner with white and then invert the image. Or extend borders and then apply morphology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the contours are closed, seed filling or polygon filling are standard methods. When they are not, morphological closing as large as the contour interruptions can help.

The "left side" effect that you see is due to the dilation reaching the left edge. If you enlarge the image on the left, this will no more be produced (as long as the two shapes do not come in contact).

Comment: That is what I said above in my comments. Pad the image out larger with black.

Comment: Thanks Yves&fmw42! after using the ```np.pad``` function the problem was solved!

Comment: See also cv2.copyMakeBorder()